# How to use python poetry to install package to a virtualenv in a standalone fashion?

Tags: python, virtualenv, python-poetry

I've recently migrated to `poetry` for my dependencies management so pardon if my question is out of the scope of `poetry` here.

#### Final goal

My final goal is to create a **RPM package** that contains a **virtualenv with my software installed along with all its dependencies**. This RPM would then provide my software in **isolation** with the system where it is installed.

#### Reproduce the problem

I'm facing a problem while using `poetry install` in my `virtualenv`. As soon as the *source directory* of my software is deleted, my *CLI* refuses to work any longer.

##### Reproduce

I've created a simple repository to reproduce the problem: https://github.com/riton/python-poetry-venv

Here are the  that I'm using with `poetry`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash -ex

VENV_DIR="/venv"
SRC_DIR="/src"
ALT_SRC_DIR="/src2"
USER_CACHE_DIR="~/.cache"

# Copy directory (cause we're mounting it read-only in the container)
# and we want to remove the source directory later on
cp -r $SRC_DIR $ALT_SRC_DIR

# We'll remove this directory to test if the soft is still working
# without the source dir
cd $ALT_SRC_DIR

[...]

python3.8 -m venv "$VENV_DIR"

source $VENV_DIR/bin/activate

[...]

poetry install --no-dev -v

[...]

# Our software will be called without an activated virtualenv
# so 'deactivate' the current one
deactivate

cd /

echo "Try after install"

# Start the "CLI" after installation
$VENV_DIR/bin/python-poetry-venv

echo "Removing source directory and trying again"
rm -rf $ALT_SRC_DIR

$VENV_DIR/bin/python-poetry-venv

echo "Removing user cache dir and trying again"
rm -rf $USER_CACHE_DIR

$VENV_DIR/bin/python-poetry-venv
```

The script above fails with the following error:

```
[...]
Try after install
+ /venv/bin/python-poetry-venv
THIS IS THE MAIN
+ echo 'Removing source directory and trying again'
Removing source directory and trying again
+ rm -rf /src2
+ /venv/bin/python-poetry-venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/venv/bin/python-poetry-venv", line 2, in <module>
    from python_poetry_venv.cli import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'python_poetry_venv'
make: *** [Makefile:2: test-with-poetry-install] Error 1
```

[link to the full script source](https://github.com/riton/python-poetry-venv/blob/master/tools/install-using-poetry.sh)

As soon as the *source directory* is removed. The CLI refuses to work any longer.

##### Trying with `pip install`

I've tried to replace the `poetry install` with something like `poetry build && pip install dist/*.whl` ([link to this script version](https://github.com/riton/python-poetry-venv/blob/master/tools/install-using-pip.sh))

With the version using `pip install` of the `.whl` file, I'm successfully creating a *standalone deployment* of my application. This is suitable to RPM packaging and could be deployed anywhere.

##### Software versions

```
+ python3.8 -V        
Python 3.8.13
          
+ poetry --version   
Poetry version 1.1.13
```

#### Final thoughts

I can't help but think that I'm misusing `poetry` here. So any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: You don't need to activate the virtualenv, poetry handles it for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm late to the party, but I want to suggest a way to accomplish this.
While `poetry` is amazing at managing your project's main and dev dependencies and locking their versions, I wouldn't rely on it while deploying on your situation. Here's a way to solve it:

```bash
# export your dependencies in the requirements.txt format using poetry
poetry export --without-hashes -f requirements.txt -o requirements.txt

# create your venv like you did on your example (you may want to upgrade pip/wheel/setuptools first)
python3 -m venv venv && . venv/bin/activate

# then install the dependencies
pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# then you install your own project
pip install .
```

There you have it, everything you need will be self-contained in the `venv` folder